# iOS-Hierarchy-Viewer build failed : linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, linker, command, hierarchy, viewer

I find a project called "[iOS-Hierarchy-Viewer](https://github.com/glock45/iOS-Hierarchy-Viewer)" that can inspect the ios native Views.
so I create a project called "ViewViewer" and do as the workaround of the "Installation" just README.md describles.
however, when I build it, and failed.

error:

```
Ld /Users/hundsun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iphone-gsuyenresnoeexcuqguzciigntxr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ViewViewer.app/ViewViewer normal i386
cd /Users/hundsun/Documents/projects/ViewViewer
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
......
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libiOSHierarchyViewer_fat.a(HVCoreDataHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSRelationshipDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libiOSHierarchyViewer_fat.a(HVCoreDataHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libiOSHierarchyViewer_fat.a(HVCoreDataHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libiOSHierarchyViewer_fat.a(HVCoreDataHandler.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

sorry for my litte konwledge of ios,object-C,C and xcode. 
thanks for telling me how to solve the problem step by step.
thanks for your detail answer!!!

Comment: If you're just getting started, you might have an easier time with something like the Spark Inspector. It's not free, but you don't have to build anything or configure your project by hand. (Full disclosure: I'm the author of that tool!)

Answer (score 3):

Please add CoreData.framework to Frameworks section.